# Find intersection between highways and GeoJSON polygon

Tags: python, openstreetmap, geojson, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I have a GeoJSON which shows an area like so:

[image]

There are some highways, crossing this GeoJSON. I need to output the coordinates of each highway entering and exiting this polygon with Python.

First, I need to find the data for all the highways in this area, and then find a way to output the intersection between them.
I could find some data using overpass turbo like so:

```
[out:json];
way["highway"~"motorway|trunk"]
(49.8194,8.3249,50.3218,9.7202);
out meta;
>;
out skel qt;
```

[image]

but I have no idea if this data is useful in anyway, or if it is, how I can use it.
I'm new to all of this.

**UPDATE:**

I also tried this query which turns nodes to coordinates in the resulting json. But I still have no idea how I may be able to use this.

```
[out:json];
way["highway"~"motorway|trunk"]
(49.8194,8.3249,50.3218,9.7202);
convert item ::=::,::geom=geom(),_osm_type=type();
out geom;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the way to do this in case anyone might want to do something similar. I used [shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html) package to work with geojson data.

##### Find the bounding box:

Since I wanted to work with the data inside my region, I needed the bounding box of the polygon. So I used `bounds` function from shapely like so: [Docs](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#:%7E:text=Returns%20a%20(minx%2C%20miny%2C%20maxx%2C%20maxy)%20tuple%20(float%20values)%20that%20bounds%20the%20object.)

```py
with open('region.geojson', 'r') as r:
  r_content = json.load(r)
  coordinates = r_content['coordinates'][0]
  region = Polygon(coordinates)
  print(region.bounds)  # output: (7.638, 49.574, 9.469, 50.699)
```

##### Find the data from [Overpass turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/):

Use overpass turbo to filter the osm data and get what you need. since I wanted the data for all highways starting with `A` in their ref in my boundary, I used the below query with [regex](http://osmlab.github.io/learnoverpass/en/docs/filters/tag/): (highways like: `ref=A 3`, `ref=A 5`, ...)

*remember to use the bounding box in the correct order for overpass* [Docs](https://dev.overpass-api.de/overpass-doc/en/full_data/bbox.html#:%7E:text=Filter%20Globally-,Filter%20a%20Query,-The%20simplest%20way)

```
[out:xml];
way["ref"~"^A"]
(49.574, 7.638, 50.699, 9.469);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

This will give all the needed data in `xml` format. I wanted to work with `geojson`, so I exported it as `geojson` from overpass turbo.

[image]

[image]

##### Find the intersection points:

Now we have the region and the highway's data, we can find their intersection with the help of shapely `intersection` method.[Docs](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#:%7E:text=object.intersection(other))

- Remember that the intersection between a **Polygon** and a **LineString** is a **LineString**, and the intersection between **two LineString** is a **Point**. So we need to convert the Polygon to a LineString first.

```
ring = LineString(list(region.exterior.coords)) # convert Polygon to Linestring

with open('A_data.geojson', 'rb') as a:
  a_content = json.load(a)
  for feature in a_content['features']:
    # get all LineStrings which have the highway tag
    if feature['geometry']['type'] == 'LineString' and feature['properties'].get('highway'):      
      line = LineString(Point(list(cor)[0], list(cor)[1]) for cor in feature['geometry']['coordinates'])
      if ring.intersection(line):
          point = (ring.intersection(line))
          print(f"intersection point for {feature['properties']['ref']}: ", point)
```